# Using a directive to attach a feature with scope access to html element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to create two search fields A and B. When the user enters a value in A, they get some results in a `<ul></ul>` from which they can choose. Now, if the user chooses a result from A (ng-click on `<li>`), I want this result to be chosen for B as well (let's call that input assist). The value should be stored by the controller on field B until the user chooses to use field B as well. However, A and B are both directives, since I need to reuse those a few times.
Additionally, I want the input assist feature to be a (set of) directive(s) as well since I need to reuse those with other form fields, too. That's where things become more crazy. Basically, I have difficulties passing data between all the scopes that are created by using different directives and controllers. Maybe I should use a completely different approach?

This is the directive that is giving me trouble. I set a `$scope.$watch` on `ctrl.selection` but it won't fire ([plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pM2QZbAwF7E2xaH51LfC)):

```
[...]
function assistReceiver() {
    return {
        require: "^inputAssist",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log("receiver: " + ctrl.selection);
            console.log(ctrl);
            scope.$watch(ctrl.selection, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log(ctrl);
                console.log("receiver: " + newVal);
                attrs.scSelection = newVal;
                attrs.scModel = newVal;
            });
        }
    };


}
```

The `ctrl.selection` is created in this controller:

```
[...]
function InputAssistController(inputAssist) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.selection = "";
}
```

Then, there's also the sender directive which has acces to the same variable and controller. This directive's job is it to listen to a variable from the attributes and fire away when the variable is changed:

```
[...]
function assistSender() {
    return {
        require: "^inputAssist",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log(scope);
            console.log(ctrl);
            scope.$watch(attrs.scWatch, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    ctrl.selection = newVal;
                }
            });
        }
    };


}
```

Here you can see which attributes are used. The code for the other directives is in the plunker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body ng-app="searchbox">

<input-assist>
    <search-box assist-sender sc-watch="sCtrl.inputModel"></search-box>
    <search-box assist-receiver sc-selection="sCtrl.selectedLens" sc-model="sCtrl.inputModel"></search-box>
</input-assist>


</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea why it's not firing? Am I using a completely useless approach? I've tried different approaches but I think this time I'm really close.

Comment: I think what you are doing might be an overkill, but I don't really understand your problem from reading the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem correctly: You want to change a value, based on another value and want to use a directive for that, because the change is always the same and can happen on different places.

Then, all you need is one directive:

```
angular
.module('searchbox')
    .directive('react', react);

react.$inject = [];
function react(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      react: '=',
      affect: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('react', function(newVal) {
        scope.affect = newVal + 'some change';
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And then supposing you have two dropdowns:

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.selection1"> .... </select>
<select ng-model="ctrl.selection2" react="ctrl.selection1" affect="ctrl.selection2>...</select>
```

#### Edit:

Please remember that you can pass objects and even functions to your directive's isolated scope:

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.complexObject.selection1"> .... </select>
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.complexObject.textInput">
<select ng-model="ctrl.selection2" react="ctrl.complexObject" affect="ctrl.selection2" affect-function="ctrl.affect(obj)">...</select>
```

and the directive

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      react: '=',
      affect: '=',
      affectFunction: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('react', function(newVal) {
        if(scope.affectFunction) {
           scope.affect = scope.affectFunction({obj: newVal});
        }
        else { //default behaviour
           scope.affect = newVal.selection1 + newVal.textInput;
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Hm, I think, I might have overthought this problem ^ ^ Thanks!

Comment: I tried to apply your answer to my problem but it was actually not that simple. So, the problem ist that I need this to work for different cases, including a case where there are two search fields. In the case with the select fields this works fine but not if I have two input fields plus an unsorted list of results that also have click-event attached to them. Could you have a look at the plunker? I'm not even sure if I'm using the right approach.

Comment: Remember that when you pass something to your directive isolated scope, you are not limited to a single value and you can even pass functions. Please see my edit to see if that helps.

Comment: In the end, I used your solution for the more general cases and went for an individual solution with the above case. That one is admittedly a special case. Your solution applies to the other cases.